# Prevent sphinx autodoc to add classes and methods in table of content

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am generating the documentation of a python project using Sphinx / sphinx-autodoc / sphinx_rtd_theme.
Recently, I added type hints to my project which forced me to update Sphinx to the latest version (6.1) to handle these correctly. Since I updated Sphinx, all classes/functions description generated by autodoc (autoclass and automethod) now shows up in the table of content and I do not want that.

I found that I could manually add `:noindex:` to each autoclass/automethod directive, which almost works but it looks like there's a strange behaviour when I add `:noindex:` to all classes under a page. Although class and method disappear, the class members suddenly appears in the table of content.

Can I tell Sphinx to simply not put anything generated by autodoc in the table of content?

See the problem here:

1. [Master branch](https://udsoncan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) : Generated with Sphinx 1.3. Table of content is good, by method signature is polluted by typehints
2. [Dev branch](https://udsoncan.readthedocs.io/en/doc-test/udsoncan/services.html) : Sphinx 6.1 . Typehint is handled properly, but table of content is polluted by autoclass/automethod elements.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured that there's a new option to control this behavior that is enabled by default and was not present in my `conf.py` (because it was coming from a years old config.

I just had to set :  `toc_object_entries = False`  in `conf.py`